# How to read an ArrayBuffer with binary data in "4 byte single"/floating point/IEEE 754 encoded data?

Tags: javascript, filereader, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I need to loop over a binary file via an `arrayBuffer`and retrieve sets of 1024 floating points. I'm doing this:

```
// chunk_size = 1024
// chunk_len = 48
// response_buffer = ArrayBuffer
// response_buffer.byteLength = 49152
for (i = chunk_len; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    switch (i) {
        case (chunk_len):

            // create view from last chunk of 1024 out of 49152 total
            float_buffer = new Float32Array(response_buffer, ((i - 1) * chunk_size));

            // add_data(net_len, float_buffer);
            break;

        case 0:
            break;

        default:
            float_buffer = new Float32Array(response_buffer, ((i - 1) * chunk_size)), chunk_size);
            //add_data(net_len, float_buffer);
            break;
    }
}
```

My problem is if I call this on the first run for the end of my buffer:

```
// i - 1 = 47 * chunk_size
new Float32Array(response_buffer, ((i - 1) * chunk_size));
```

the same statement fails on the next run where I call:

```
new Float32Array(response_buffer, ((i - 1) * chunk_size), 1024);
```

Although I can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array), that 
I can do this:

```
Float32Array Float32Array(
    ArrayBuffer buffer,
    optional unsigned long byteOffset,
    optional unsigned long length
);
```

**Question**:
Why is my loop failing after declaring the first `Float32Array` view on my `response_offer` ArrayBuffer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an extra ")" in the first line of your "default" case.

```
float_buffer = new Float32Array(response_buffer, ((i - 1) * chunk_size)), chunk_size);
```

Should be:

```
float_buffer = new Float32Array(response_buffer, ((i - 1) * chunk_size), chunk_size);
```

Comment: nice spot. But that's not it. I get the same error, when I use hardcoded numbers. See my edit above.

Comment: Cool. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

So. Finally understand... maybe this helps the next person wondering:

First off - I was all wrong in trying to read my data, which is **4 byte single format**.

- If I have an `arrayBuffer` with `byteLength = 49182` this means there are that many entries in my array.
- Since my array is `4 byte single format`, I found out with some [SO-help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844960/what-does-it-mean-if-binary-data-is-4-byte-single-format-and-how-do-i-read-it) and [searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) that this is readable with `getFloat32` **AND** that 4 entries comprise one "real" value
- My data contains **3** measurements a **4000** data points stored in units of **1024** column by column.
- So if I have 12000 data-points and  49182/4 = 12288 datapoints, I will have 288 empty data points at the end of my data structure.
- So my binary data should be stored like this:

  ```
        0 -  1024    a
     1025 -  2048    a
     2049 -  3072    a
     3072 -  4000   [a
     4001 -  4096    b]
     4097 -  5120    b
     5121 -  6144    b
     6145 -  7168    b
     7169 -  8000   [b
     8001 -  8192    c]
     8193 -  9216    c
     9217 - 10240    c
    10240 - 11264    c
    11264 - 12000   [c
    12000 - 12288    0]
  ```
- My final snippet will contain 288 empty results, because 3x4000 datapoints in 1024 chunks will return some empty results
- To read, I found a nice snippet [here (dynamic high range rendering)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/), which helped me to this:

  ```
    // ...
    raw_data = ...
    data = new DataView(raw_data);

    ...
    tmp_data = new Float32Array(byte_len / Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
    len = tmp_data.length;

    // Incoming data is raw floating point values with little-endian byte ordering.
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
      tmp_data[i] = data.getFloat32(i * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, true);
    }
  ```
- Now I have a single array with which I can work and build my processing structure.